# Is it okay to always use same variable (e.g. $stmt) for PDO queries?

Tags: php, pdo

I always use the same variable for my PDO query statements, for example:

```
// Query 1
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table_1 SET name=? WHERE somthing=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $something, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();


// Query 2 (right after the above)
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table_2 SET another_column=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $another_column, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

I know it is ok for the first lines `($stmt = $db->...)`, my doubt is about binding values. For example if I forget to bind something in first query will my query use the next binding in second query (or vice versa)? or everything is reset after `execute()`?

Which one is a better practice?

1. Using same variable to avoid mistakes (e.g. Always $stmt)
2. Using different variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using different variables makes it easier to debug, however I do this occasionally because it is easier to type-hint a single statement.

> my doubt is about binding values.

each `db->prepare()` returns a brand new `\PDOStatement` so there is no issue about binding values.

Comment: Different variables also make it easier to maintain. Say if the logic changes and you need to access the first `PDOStatement` after already reassigning the variable `$stmt`.

Comment: @topher: I'd call it harder to maintain if i have bunch of variables _just in case_. A number of those statements won't be in a useful state anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, different statements used in the same scope, I choose more specific names for the statements.

So in your case I would name them `$stmtUpdTable1` and `$stmtUpdTable2` or something along those lines.

Since I can't comment other answers: I think it is unnecessary to unset variables which are no longer used, the garbage collector will do his job. No need to make the code messy

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to unset `$stmt` after each query. So I don't have to worry about all the things which you have mentioned above.

```
// Query 1
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table_1 SET name=? WHERE somthing=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $something, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();


unset($stmt);

// Query 2 (right after the above)
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table_2 SET another_column=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $another_column, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Also its a good practice to unset variable which are not required any more.

Comment: Could any one back this up please? I also sometimes do such things because of my doubts, so I thought I should ask, maybe such actions are not required at all?

Comment: @Ara: They're not required. A new object stored in `$stmt` replaces the old value, bindings and all.

Comment: Why bother with the `unset()`? In garbage collection, once the `PDOStatement` object [no longer has any references to it](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/12/what-about-garbage.html), it is automatically deleted.

Comment: @cHao / Machavity Could you please upvote the better answer(s)?